# YouTube "don't recommend this channel" settings reset

Tags: youtube

I have removed a YouTube channel from recommendations by clicking the "don't recommend this channel". I would like to undo that setting.

How to reset/re-enable a channel to appear again in my recommendations after doing the above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Google support website:

Clear “Not interested” and “Don’t recommend channel” feedback:

Your “Not Interested” and “Don’t recommend channel” feedback may be used to tune your recommendations. To clear all “Not interested” and “Don’t recommend channel” feedback:

1. Go to MyActivity.google.com You might need to sign in to your Google Account.
2. In the left Menu, find Other Google activity.
3. Select "YouTube 'Not interested' feedback", then select Delete.

Comment: that works, thx!

Comment: although this doesn't take care of individual channels, obviously...